# How can I use Facebook Messenger Platform's webhook to subscribe to the Page messages of other users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger

I am creating an application using which users will manage their Facebook messenger and post comments on a page. I have implemented the Facebook Login which asks the user for `page_messaging` permission. I have also configured the webhook and it is working fine.

Now, Facebook documentation states the following

> Generate a Page access token to start using the platform APIs. You
> will be able to generate an access token for a Page if:
>
> 1. You are one of the Page admins, and
> 2. The app has been granted the Page's permission to manage and access Page conversations in Messenger.

So, how can I make my webhook listen to the messages of the page that have granted me permission to manage and access the page? I have looked for hours trying to find this in the documentation. No Luck!

Comment: hey, any success with this?